# Docker-compose: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to create an Apache container and mount current working directory as a volume in container, so I have this code:

```
volumes:
    - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/var/www/html
```

The value of ${DOCUMENT_ROOT} is a dot in `.env` file:

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT=.
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file is at the root of my project directory and in my project directory there is a `.docker` directory.

I tried this 3 lines:

```
volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html

volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html

volumes:
    - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/var/www/html
```

But I have this error:

```
Creating 7.4.x-webserver ... error ERROR: for 7.4.x-webserver  Cannot
create container for service webserver: b'create .: volume name is too
short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters'

ERROR: for webserver  Cannot create container for service webserver:
b'create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two
alphanumeric characters' ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up
the project. Failed to deploy 'Compose: docker-compose.yml':
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1
```

The content of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
webserver:
    build:
        context: ./.docker/bin/webserver
    container_name: '7.4.x-webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
        - "${HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT}:80"
        - "${HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT}:443"
    links:
        - mysql
    volumes:
        - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/var/www/html
        - ${PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
        - ${VHOSTS_DIR}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
        - ${LOG_DIR}:/var/log/apache2

mysql:
    build:
        context: "./.docker/bin/${DATABASE}"
    container_name: 'mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
        - "${HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    volumes:
        - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}:/var/lib/mysql
        - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'sc-phpmyadmin'
    links:
        - mysql
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        PMA_PORT: 3306
        PMA_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
        - '${HOST_MACHINE_PHPMYADMIN_PORT}:80'
    volumes:
        - ./.docker/sessions

redis:
    container_name: 'sc-redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
        - "${HOST_MACHINE_REDIS_PORT}:6379"
```

.env:

```sh
###>  docker ###
DOCUMENT_ROOT=.

VHOSTS_DIR=./.docker/config/vhosts
APACHE_LOG_DIR=./.docker/logs/apache2
PHP_INI=./.docker/config/php/php.ini

DATABASE=mysql8

MYSQL_DATA_DIR=./.docker/data/mysql
MYSQL_LOG_DIR=./.docker/logs/mysql

HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT=80
HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT=443
HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT=3306
HOST_MACHINE_PHPMYADMIN_PORT=8080
HOST_MACHINE_REDIS_PORT=6379

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=tiger
MYSQL_USER=docker
MYSQL_PASSWORD=docker
MYSQL_DATABASE=docker
###>  docker ###
```

How to fix this error please ?

In advance, thank you for your help

Comment: Try replacing the relative (`./`) references with absolute references.

Comment: I got this error when accidentally running docker-compose command in a wrong folder

Comment: When passing volumes to `docker run` doing e.g. `-v .:/work` will give you the message from the OP title. However, doing `-v ./:/work` produces the more informative: `"./" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.`

Answer (score 38):

try something like this `- ${PWD}/:/var/www/html`

Comment: turns out the `/` was crucial here:  `--volume $(pwd)/:/app` works but not `--volume $(pwd):/app`

Comment: without `/` worked to me

Answer (score 25):

I struggled with this a lot. The only change I made - added a forward slash. Worked.

As-Is

```
  volumes:
      - ${PWD}:/apps
```

To-Be

```
  volumes:
      - ${PWD}/:/apps
```

Comment: I worked for me! So frustrating after hours spent managing containers....

Answer (score 3):

I tried `${PWD} --> C:/path(example)` in `docker-compose.yml` file. This works for me. (Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this issue is being `cd`ed into a subdirectory of the Docker project. Just `cd` into the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file and try again.

Example:

```bash
dotan@deathstar:~/project/docker-services/php$ docker-compose up --build -d
... Lots of lines here ...
Successfully built 0e9ea46affe0
Successfully tagged foobar_php:latest
Creating foobar_mysql_1 ... done
Creating foobar_php_1   ... error
ERROR: for foobar_php_1  Cannot create container for service php: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
ERROR: for php  Cannot create container for service php: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

dotan@deathstar:~/project/docker-services/php$ cd ../..

dotan@deathstar:~/project/$ docker-compose up --build -d
... Lots of lines here ...
Successfully built 0e9ea46affe0
Successfully tagged foobar_php:latest
Creating foobar_mysql_1 ... done
Creating foobar_php_1   ... done
Creating foobar_nginx_1 ... done
```